# Change appearance of a popover created using a popover segue in OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, storyboard, osx-yosemite

I'm trying to use storyboards to build a simple app for Yosemite.  Creating a popover segue is easy - the segue is created from a button click to an `NSViewController` in my storyboard, and the Style is set to Popover.  This works great, but the trouble is, I'd like to change the appearance of this popover.  It seems to be defaulting to a Vibrant Dark appearance, but I'd like it to be Vibrant Light or Aqua.  I assume what is happening here is that behind the scenes, an `NSPopover` is being created to contain the view controller that I am displaying with my segue, but I can't figure out how to get access to this `NSPopover` object - the storyboard only gives me access to the view controller that I am displaying, and there isn't any `NSPopover` object available to use in interface builder.

All I want to do is change the appearance of this popover I'm creating in my storyboard...Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: You should mark @inkbits' answer as accepted to thank him/her, since it is correct. Have an up-vote for a good question, since I was looking for this same thing (it hadn't occurred to me to target the popover's *window* for appearance change; I was targeting the view and nothing was happening).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Override `viewWillAppear` in your view controller and update the appearance of the view's window:

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    self.view.window?.appearance = NSAppearance(named: NSAppearanceNameVibrantDark)
}
```

your appearance can be any of the [standard appearances](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSAppearance_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Standard_Appearances)

Comment: Was getting annoyed with this very problem for the last ten minutes. Learn something new every day. Thanks, and have an up-vote. :-)